# Vertx program memory keeps growing

Tags: vert.x

I used the top command to check on the Linux server, and found that the Memory of the deployed Vertx program has been increasing. I printed the Memory usage with Native Memory Tracking, and found that the Internal Memory has been increasing.I didn't manually allocate out of heap memory in the code.

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=7595MB, committed=6379MB

- ```
              Java Heap (reserved=4096MB, committed=4096MB)
                        (mmap: reserved=4096MB, committed=4096MB)
  ```
- ```
                  Class (reserved=1101MB, committed=86MB)
                        (classes #12776)
                        (malloc=7MB #18858) 
                        (mmap: reserved=1094MB, committed=79MB)
  ```
- ```
                 Thread (reserved=122MB, committed=122MB)
                        (thread #122)
                        (stack: reserved=121MB, committed=121MB)
  ```
- ```
                   Code (reserved=253MB, committed=52MB)
                        (malloc=9MB #12566) 
                        (mmap: reserved=244MB, committed=43MB)
  ```
- ```
                     GC (reserved=155MB, committed=155MB)
                        (malloc=6MB #302) 
                        (mmap: reserved=150MB, committed=150MB)
  ```
- ```
               Internal (reserved=1847MB, committed=1847MB)
                        (malloc=1847MB #35973)
  ```
- ```
                 Symbol (reserved=17MB, committed=17MB)
                        (malloc=14MB #137575) 
                        (arena=3MB #1)
  ```
- Native Memory Tracking (reserved=4MB, committed=4MB)
  (tracking overhead=3MB)

vertx version:3.9.8
Cluster:Hazelcast
startup script:su web -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -javaagent:../target/showbiz-server-game-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar -javaagent:../../quasar-core-0.8.0.jar=b -Dvertx.hazelcast.config=/data/appdata/webdata/Project/config/cluster.xml -jar -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow ../target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar start-Dvertx-id=server -conf application-conf.json -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2_logstash.xml -cluster >nohup.out 2>&1 &"

Comment: I recommend checking the resources you setup in the Verticle `start()` make sure you release / close all of them in the Verticle `stop()`,  Check custom executors especially. 
 Also check static maps, list, etc. those are never released and usually keep growing.

Comment: If I send a message to Verticle and Verticle doesn't return a message, will memory keep growing?
For example, the code sent is
eventBus.request(address, message, handler->{})
But Verticle does not execute message.reply(obj);

Comment: I don't know.  but I will not be surprised if messages not replied causing some queue to grow.  possible.  (you easily test that by replying those messages).

Answer (score 1):

If your producers are much faster than your consumers, and back pressure isn't handled properly, it's possible to have memory that keeps increasing.

Also, this could vary depending on how the code is written.

[This similar reported issue](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/760) could be of help and consider exploring [writeStream](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_writestream) too.